# JSOUP - Getting value of textarea from HTML - CLOSED

Tags: java, textarea, jsoup

I've just started using JSOUP and I'm trying to get the value in the textarea. The below is the element info from the HTML;

[image]

The below is the code that I'm using to attempt to read the value in the textarea;

```
    try {
        String html = "http://aviprobo.doorfree.com/control.html";
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(html).get();
        Element textarea = doc.getElementById("control");
        System.out.println("textarea value = " + textarea.val());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //
    }
```

The value of textarea.val() is empty. Could someone please point me in the right direction.
Thanks.

Comment: did you try `textarea.getText()`?

Comment: Hi Xbit, yes I have tried textarea.text() but its still showing up blank.

Comment: The correct value is being returned. The textarea remains empty until one of the button controls is clicked

Comment: If you print content of `doc` you will see that `textarea` is empty at start. It gets values only after user interactions which JSoup can't send/emulate. Maybe take a look at WebDriver instead of HTML parser.

Comment: Thanks Reimeus and Pshemo.
Pshemo, thanks for the suggestion, I'm now using Selenium WebDriver.

Comment: Please provide an answer of your own and accept it, or mark it as closed  in the title

Answer (score 0):

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://sports.163.com/13/0830/22/97IFSI5I00051CD5.html").get();

**Entities.EscapeMode.base.getMap().clear();**

Elements elements = doc.select("textarea[id^=photoList]");

for(Element e:elements){
    System.out.println(e.html());
}
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit?

Comment: Please put some commentary so that answer is better understood.